# JsGrid not responsive bug

Tags: jsgrid

Im using jsGrid, not jqGrid..

I have bug problem on column.
here is the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css rule:

```
.jsgrid-cell { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

See the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/kL291xp5/

Comment: Oops, forgot to save changes. As you saw it had no css above. Look at it now (refresh the page).

Comment: but this is just hide the value.. how can i pushed it so it responsive?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "responsive". If you want text to be wrapped you can use `word-wrap: break-word` (https://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/kL291xp5/10/). You could also truncate text with ellipsis (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: OK Thx, your jsGrid is awesome.. i love it.